# Map Markers Not Displaying (JavaScript/Google Maps API V3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm having trouble getting map markers to display using Google Maps API v3.  I'm attempting to keep them all in a single array, to make displaying a large amount relatively simple.  Currently, the map loads fine, but throws the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setValues'` when attempting to draw the markers.  The error repeats with each iteration run by the `setTimeout()`.  Any recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

This is the JavaScript used:

```
var map;
var markers = [
    [
        45.768366,
        -108.5975760,
        'Fitness 19'
    ],
    [
        45.785684,
        -108.6144625,
        'Granite Fitness'
    ],
      ... (more, syntactically correct)
    [
        45.7920092,
        -108.4886232,
        'Steepworld'
    ]
];
function mapinit() {
    var conf = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.7832856,-108.5006904),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapcont'),conf);
    for(i in markers) {
        window.setTimeout('mark('+i+')',i*200);
    }
}
function mark(i){
    google.maps.Marker({
        position: google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0],markers[i][1]),
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: markers[i][2]
    });
}
```

Comment: cleaned it up a bit:
function mark(i){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0],markers[i][1]),
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: markers[i][2],
        
    });
}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, after quite a bit of messing around in Chrome's JavaScript console (I love that thing), I was able to get it working perfectly.  I rewrote the `mapinit()` and `mark()` functions to this:

```
function mapinit() {
    var conf = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.7832856,-108.5006904),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapcont'),conf);
    for(i in markers) {
        markers[i][3] = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][0],markers[i][1]);
        window.setTimeout('mark('+i+')',i*200);
    }
}
function mark(i){
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markers[i][3],
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][2]
    });
}
```

The main difference here is that the `position` variable of the marker seems to require being initialized in an outside variable for some reason, so when I loop through the `markers` array, I generate a `google.maps.LatLng` as the fourth item for each marker.  This is then referenced within the `mark()` function, and the marker displays successfully.  The `setTimeout` for staggering the display of the markers works wonderfully, especially on faster connections where the scripts and map load quickly.

View the end result [on my inClass site](http://www.inclass.org/letsmove/resources.php)

Answer (score 6):

It's the `new` keyword that makes all the difference!

I had the same problem. Using the new keyword when constructing the Marker object makes it work again in Chrome at least. Putting it in a differed timeout event didn't. And here I thought `new` was nothing but syntactic sugar...