# error :this.setValues is not a function in js code use google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

here is code of java script :

```
<script>
        function initMap() {
            var lat = 10;
            var lng = 10;
            var propertyCenter = {lat: 10, lng: 10};
            var propertymap = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                zoom: 7,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("propmap"), propertymap);

            var marker = google.maps.Marker({
                position: propertyCenter

            });
            marker.setMap(map);

        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

    </script>
```

I am getting following error on console :

js?key=my_key&callback=initMap:65 **Uncaught TypeError: this.setValues is not a function**

Answer (score 41):

Take a look at [Map Markers Not Displaying (JavaScript/Google Maps API V3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089479/map-markers-not-displaying-javascript-google-maps-api-v3)

Try changing

```
var marker = google.maps.Marker
```

to

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker
```

Adding `new` should fix your issue

This also applies to the library `load-google-maps-api` for those using webpack.

```
loadGoogleMapsAPI().then((googleMaps) => {
  new googleMaps.Map(element, {options})
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
})
```