# this.setValues is not a function google maps API 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know this question has been asked before and I have followed a few answers but none seems to work. The closest I got was this one

[Map Markers Not Displaying (JavaScript/Google Maps API V3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089479/map-markers-not-displaying-javascript-google-maps-api-v3)

But here I don't know what he trying to do and nonetheless I think my case is different and it didn't work for me.
So please if anyone have any sugeestions please tell me.

```js
function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5498783, 13.425209099999961),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
            
            overlay = new DraggableOverlay(map,
                                           map.getCenter(),
                                           '<div class="overlay">drag me!</div>'
                      );


        }
        
        DraggableOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

        DraggableOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function () {
            var container = document.createElement('div'),
                that = this;

            if (typeof this.get('content').nodeName !== 'undefined') {
                container.appendChild(this.get('content'));
            }
            else {
                if (typeof this.get('content') === 'string') {
                    container.innerHTML = this.get('content');
                }
                else {
                    return;
                }
            }
            container.style.position = 'absolute';
            container.draggable = true;
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.get('map').getDiv(),
                                             'mouseleave',
                                              function () {
                                                  google.maps.event.trigger(container, 'mouseup');
                                              }
            );


            google.maps.event.addDomListener(container,
                                             'mousedown',
                                         function (e) {
                                             this.style.cursor = 'move';
                                             that.map.set('draggable', false);
                                             that.set('origin', e);

                                             that.moveHandler = google.maps.event.addDomListener(that.get('map').getDiv(),
                                                                                                  'mousemove',
                                                                                                  function (e) {
                                                                                                      var origin = that.get('origin'),
                                                                                                          left = origin.clientX - e.clientX,
                                                                                                          top = origin.clientY - e.clientY,
                                                                                                          pos = that.getProjection()
                                                                                                                    .fromLatLngToDivPixel(that.get('position')),
                                                                                                          latLng = that.getProjection()
                                                                                                                    .fromDivPixelToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(pos.x - left,
                                                                                                                                                                pos.y - top));
                                                                                                      that.set('origin', e);
                                                                                                      that.set('position', latLng);
                                                                                                      that.draw();
                                                                                                  });


                                         }
           );

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(container, 'mouseup', function () {
                that.map.set('draggable', true);
                this.style.cursor = 'default';
                google.maps.event.removeListener(that.moveHandler);
            });


            this.set('container', container)
            this.getPanes().floatPane.appendChild(container);
        };

        function DraggableOverlay(map, position, content) {
            if (typeof draw === 'function') {
                this.draw = draw;
            }
            this.setValues({
                position: position,
                container: null,
                content: content,
                map: map
            });
        }



        DraggableOverlay.prototype.draw = function () {
            var pos = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));
            this.get('container').style.left = pos.x + 'px';
            this.get('container').style.top = pos.y + 'px';
        };

        DraggableOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function () {
            this.get('container').parentNode.removeChild(this.get('container'));
            this.set('container', null)
        };


        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      .overlay{
        background:yellow;
        padding:30px;
        border:4px double black;
      }
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD7FTNE22Wl6S6DTQF83sTZTqbFFPzEkmU&libraries=drawing,places,geometry&callback=initialize">
    
   </script>
```

So here as you can see I am getting two issues

- Google is not defined
- this.setValues is not a function

So please if anyone faced this issue let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`google is not defined`:  if you are asynchronously loading the API, you need to put *all* the code that depends on the API inside the callback function (`initialize` in your case).  Anything that depends on the API won't work until the API is loaded. 
You would need to move the definition of `DraggableOverlay` inside `initialize` or load the API synchronously.

Example below without the asynchronous load of the API (like [the example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple) and [Dr.Molle's answer that it looks like the `DraggableOverlay` came from: Can we make custom overlays draggable on google maps V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127626/can-we-make-custom-overlays-draggable-on-google-maps-v3))

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5498783, 13.425209099999961),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  overlay = new DraggableOverlay(map,
    map.getCenter(),
    '<div class="overlay">drag me!</div>'
  );
}

DraggableOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
DraggableOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  var container = document.createElement('div'),
    that = this;

  if (typeof this.get('content').nodeName !== 'undefined') {
    container.appendChild(this.get('content'));
  } else {
    if (typeof this.get('content') === 'string') {
      container.innerHTML = this.get('content');
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
  container.style.position = 'absolute';
  container.draggable = true;
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.get('map').getDiv(),
    'mouseleave',
    function() {
      google.maps.event.trigger(container, 'mouseup');
    }
  );

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(container,
    'mousedown',
    function(e) {
      this.style.cursor = 'move';
      that.map.set('draggable', false);
      that.set('origin', e);

      that.moveHandler = google.maps.event.addDomListener(that.get('map').getDiv(),
        'mousemove',
        function(e) {
          var origin = that.get('origin'),
            left = origin.clientX - e.clientX,
            top = origin.clientY - e.clientY,
            pos = that.getProjection()
            .fromLatLngToDivPixel(that.get('position')),
            latLng = that.getProjection()
            .fromDivPixelToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(pos.x - left,
              pos.y - top));
          that.set('origin', e);
          that.set('position', latLng);
          that.draw();
        });
    }
  );
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(container, 'mouseup', function() {
    that.map.set('draggable', true);
    this.style.cursor = 'default';
    google.maps.event.removeListener(that.moveHandler);
  });
  this.set('container', container)
  this.getPanes().floatPane.appendChild(container);
};

function DraggableOverlay(map, position, content) {
  if (typeof draw === 'function') {
    this.draw = draw;
  }
  this.setValues({
    position: position,
    container: null,
    content: content,
    map: map
  });
};


DraggableOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
  var pos = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));
  this.get('container').style.left = pos.x + 'px';
  this.get('container').style.top = pos.y + 'px';
};

DraggableOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
  this.get('container').parentNode.removeChild(this.get('container'));
  this.set('container', null)
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
.overlay {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 4px double black;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing,places,geometry">
</script>
```